# Regular expression lowercase

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using this regex to lowercase prepositions, conjunctions, etc. in text files, and I want to add 2 exceptions: do not lowercase when $1 is preceded by ":" or preceded by "-". What is the proper, concise way to do that. Thanks.

```
s/(\s(?:a|about|an|and|at|by|for|from|in|is|it|of|on|the|to|with))\b/\L$1/gi;
```

Comment: I love regex questions involving lookaround.

Comment: A bigger list of prepositions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a negated look-behind before `$1`:

```
(?<![:-])
```

Comment: And welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) (if you haven't so) and if this answer really solves your problem, don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Comment: But a character class is better than alternation: (?<![:-])